# Adding Row to JTable with "Real-Time Feeling"

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtable

I'm trying to make "Realtime Feeling JTable". I made GUI with JTable, and then there is a button named **START**. When I click this button, the program will call below start() method. (It's just an example). Adding row is no problem, It works well. But the problem is, rows come to Jtable just at **one time.** (maybe program finish start() method, The rows come up with at all together.) There is 1000 more statement in my start() method. It's not realtime feeling. I shoud wait until start method finished. and then 1000 rows added **at once**.

```
void start(){    
    int a = 3+3;
    addRow(new String[]{"a is 6"})   
    int b = 4+4;
    addRow(new String[]{"b is 8 "})
}
```

What I'm gonna do is just "Real Time Feeling", I want to see adding row **one by one**, not at once. Could you understand my purpose? Imagine "Fiddler" Program. you can understand easily. Can anyone help me? Should I make a Thread?

Thanks for reading, and sorry for ackward expression(english is not my language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the way Swing threading works. There is one single thread that handles all rendering, updating, etc. Your processing of the start() method is happening inside that render thread so nothing else on the GUI will respond until you return from the method.

What you need to do is use a `SwingWorker` or a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and farm the processing off to another thread. That can then update the GUI on a regular basis as the processing continues.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Note that by doing this people can potentially click the button multiple times and call `start()` again before the first one has finished. You will need to consider and handle that case - for example by disabling the button until the first one completes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Swing based `Timer`.  In the `actionPerformed(..)` add a new record.  See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

In swing there is a thread called EDT (Event Dispatcher Thread) that is responsible for GUI to behave like a real time, user friednly app. If you interfer EDT with a long running method you will freeze your app GUI. You have to do long running tasks in background (in a thread different than EDT). You can do this by using `javax.swing.SwingWorker<T,V>` or `javax.swing.Timer`